# What is this tsql "method"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery

Where can I find info on this tsql "method" .query()? I just ran across it the other day.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT top 10 * from something
    FOR XML PATH, ELEMENTS, TYPE
).query('for $e in row
         return 
         <row>
         {
             for $f in $e/*
             return <item name="{local-name($f)}">{data($f)}</item>
         }
         </row>')
```

Answer (score 4):

That's [XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28SQL.90%29.aspx) query against [XML data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Xquery